# Joomla k2 custom fields - error DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string

Tags: php, datetime, joomla, content-management-system

By default, in k2 in the custom "Date" field, you can select only one value, changing the datepicker to the "multiple" mode gives an error on the frontend when several dates are selected - `0 - DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2017-12-29; 2017-12-30) at position 10 (;): Unexpected character`
[view error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vS1ul.jpg)
[set datepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ds6Gf.jpg)

Comment: Hi Dmitry, if you really think this is a bug, it might be better to report an issue with K2 https://github.com/getk2/k2/issues.

Comment: I saw that the error appears because of an unsupported character (;)
updating the flatpickr to the latest version, this error has disappeared and a new:
0 - DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2017-12-14, 2017-12-15) at position 12 (2): Double date specification